# When I updated Android Studio to version 4.1 Google Sceneform Plugin stopped working

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform, android-studio-2.3

Google Sceneform was not working as expected and at the same there was a prompt to update Android Studio(which I assumed would solve the problem). But after updating Android Studio to version 4.1 , I got the following error.

```
Plugin Error: Plugin "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).
```

Is this a non fixable error? Do I have to downgrade to a previous version of Android Studio? Additionally is there other plugins similar to Google Sceneform or do I have to resort to learning Google ARCore with OpenGL?

Comment: Given that [Google Sceneform has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference) I wouldn't be surprised if your options are to downgrade or perhaps switching to IntelliJ IDEA or changing your workflow to support the [open-source Sceneform SDK 1.16.0](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk)